# LDAP Connection to Domain not working

Tags: c#, windows, ldap

I'm fighting with my LDAP connection to the Domain.
I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter on a VM Connection is bridged and replicated with local network.

I want to create a tool which makes me possible to see username, prename, name etc... I have build up everything so far. But when I try to search for a user it says:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   System.DirectoryServices.dll
>
> Additional information: The Server is not fully functional.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Manu_Tool.DomainServices{

    class GetterServices{

        DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://testdomain.com/DC=testdomain, DC=com", "admin", "P@ssw0rd", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

        public String getUsername (string username){

            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(DE, "objectClass=User", null, SearchScope.Subtree);
            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "))";

            SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

            return sr.ToString();

            }
    }
}
```

It stops at `SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();`

I can ping the server and the firewall is disabled.

Domain Name: testdomain.com
Login: Admin
Pass: P@ssw0rd
Host Name: testserver

What could have gone wrong?

This is only the code for getting the username.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run your code.  It works for me when I put in my domain name and credentials.  Though I would recommend returning SearchResult instead of String so you get all the details.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, your code seems to run fine for me.  Though this is the way I currently pull user information from Active Directory in one of my applications.  Try it and see if it helps your situation.

Add `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` reference.

```
Principal savedUser; ;
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com", "domainUser", "password");
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(pc);
user.SamAccountName = "username";
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
savedUser = searcher.FindOne();
```

Normally these statements would be wrapped in `using` statements, but you cannot return a disposed object.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it now. This is the Code which worked for me:

```
namespace ADM
{
    class GetterSevice
    {
        static string path = "LDAP://DC=testdomain, DC=com";
        static DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry(path, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(DE, "objectClass=User", null, SearchScope.Subtree);

        public string getUsername(string username)
        {

            string finalResult = "";


            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=person)))(SAMAccountName=" + username + "))";

            SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
            {
                DirectoryEntry result = new DirectoryEntry();
                result = new DirectoryEntry(sr.Path);
                finalResult = (result.InvokeGet("SAMAccountName")).ToString();
            }


            return finalResult;
        }
```

Thanks for yout help